# How to import classes defined in other packages in same project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Project str as follows:
   myProject
        src:
            
                a.java
            
                b.java
                c.java
                d.java
 So how to import the classes defined in myLibrary package?

Comment: `import <package_name>.<class_name>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import` statement like :

```
import myLibrary.*;
```

And go through basics :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just use an import line?

`import myLibrary.MyClass;`